# How to hide i icon when adding a tooltip? [typescript]

Tags: typescript, fluent

I added a tooltip using flunt-ui/react tooltiphost and I want to hide the "i" icon that automatically added.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO064.png)

how can I add a tooltip using tooltiphost or other jsx element without that icon?

I added a tooltip using flunt-ui/react tooltiphost and I want to hide the "i" icon that automatically added.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.